# Unit Testing a getter that calls an async operation in a try catch block

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, windows-phone-8, async-await

I have the following piece of code :

```
public FuzzyPickles(IPie pieMaker)
{
    _pieMaker = pieMaker;
}  

public string PieName
{
    get
    {
        if (_pieName == null)
        {
            GetPieName();
        }
        return _pieName;
    }
}  

private async void GetPieName()
{
    string asyncPieName = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        var task = _pieMaker.GetDeliciousPieAsync();
        asyncPieName = await task;
    }
    catch (RottenFruitException e)
    {
        Debug.Write(e.Message);
    }  
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(asyncPieName))
    {
        _pieName = asyncPieName;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(PieName);
    }
}
```

And I want to write a test (I am using RhinoMocks) to verify that an exception thrown in that getter won't get me pies with rotten fruits :

```
[TestClass]
public class FuzzyTest
{
    private FuzzyPickles _pickles;
    private IPie _pieMocker;  

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _pieMocker = MockRepository.Mock<IPie>();
        _pickles = new FuzzyPickles(_pieMocker);
    }  

    [TestMethod]
    public void PieName_WhenGettingException_ShouldHandleExceptionGracefully()
    {
        _pieMocker.Stub(x => x.GetDeliciousPieAsync()).Throws(new RottenFruitException());  
        var pieName = _pickles.PieName;
        //What should I assert here ?
    }
}
```

**Now here is my real problem.**

Removing the try / catch block does not throw the exception back to the UT runner because I do not use await in the UT as it's not prototyped as async Task and getters cannot be async, therefore I cannot await, or use a function instead (Or can I ?)

That getter is bound to the UI (ie : I use it to display information in my UI, so I don't know when - if ever - it will be called), this is why I'm doing this ugly function call hack, and use NotifyPropertyChanged in it (let's not worry about cross thread exceptions here, that is not the point)

I do not want to use code behind hacks (Windows Phone 8.1 / Silverlight project).

How can I write a Unit Test that will fail if I remove the try / catch block ? What should I assert on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As properties are not `async` compatible (which is a wise design choice IMO), you could take the `IntializeXXXAsync` pattern mentioned in [Stephan Clearys blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html).

What the pattern does is make you invoke the initialization method, which is responsible for the values creation. If it fails, you can default back to `default(T)`, which in your case of string is simply `null`, and assert on it:

```
public class FuzzyPickles : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public FuzzyPickles(IPie pieMaker)
    {
        _pieMaker = pieMaker;
    }     

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _pieName;
    public string PieName
    {
        get
        {
            return _pieName;
        }
        private set 
        {
            _pieName = value;
           OnPropertyChanged()
        }
    }  

    public async Task InitializePieAsync()
    {
        string asyncPieName = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            PieName = await _pieMaker.GetDeliciousPieAsync();
        }
        catch (RottenFruitException e)
        {
             Debug.Write(e.Message);
        }  
    }
}
```

Now you initialize `FuzzyPickles`, initialize and assert that it isn't null:

```
 [TestMethod]
 public async Task PieName_WhenGettingException_ShouldHandleExceptionGracefully()
 {
      _pieMocker.Stub(x => x.GetDeliciousPieAsync()).Throws(new RottenFruitException());  

      await  _pickles.InitializePieAsync();
      var pieName = _pickles.PieName;

      Assert.IsNotNull(pieName);
 }
```

Comment: After reading Stephan's blog post, I realized that my getter will always be called, and I can move the logic to get the value outside of it, hence solving my problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Create a new method `GetPieNameAsync` which returns a `Task`. This method will be easily testable by using `await`. If you also need a fire-and-forget method for some reason, only use it to call `GetPieNameAsync()`.

```
private async void GetPieName()
{
    await GetPieNameAsync();
}

private async Task GetPieNameAsync()
{
    string asyncPieName = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        var task = _pieMaker.GetDeliciousPieAsync();
        asyncPieName = await task;
    }
    catch (RottenFruitException e)
    {
        Debug.Write(e.Message);
    }  
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(asyncPieName))
    {
        _pieName = asyncPieName;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(PieName);
    }
}
```

Comment: While your solution is technically correct, I prefer @Yuval solution which is more detailed and contains a nice blog post entry.  
  
Also I will add that the **only** reason you would have to use 
`async void` is for UI event handlers and nothing else.  
  
http://blog.filipekberg.se/2012/09/20/avoid-shooting-yourself-in-the-foot-with-tasks-and-async/ 
This blog post by Filip Ekberg is a very good article explaining why.